# Run CSS transition in one direction but not the other

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm using a CSS transition on my hyperlink elements to make their interaction appear smoother. But I also want immediate feedback when the user is waiting for it. Hence I want the new state to appear immediately, but let it fade out when the user moves away.

Here's some CSS that I'm currently using:

```css
a
{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background 1s;
}
a:hover
{
  background: #bbbbbb;
  transition: background 0s;
}
a:active
{
  background: #888888;
  transition: background 0s;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Test link</a>
```

As you can see the colour fade is in effect when leaving the element with the mouse cursor, but not when entering it.

When pressing a mouse button on the hovered link, the colour again changes immediately.

Now comes the interesting part: When the mouse button is released, I'd like the colour to fade back to the hover state. But I can't manage to do so because the `:hover` state doesn't know from which state direction it's coming and always disables the transition.

**Whatever is changed, there must be no transition when first hovering the link.**

Again in a simple state diagram:

```
State:          normal   <---------->   hover   <---------->   active
Transition:             yes         no         yes?        no
                                          (currently no)
```

Is this possible with CSS? I know I could add custom JavaScript but that would need to go to a great number of elements.

Comment: interesting :) but a simple question : why ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Because it looks nice. Not because it's necessary. I can live with what I have now but I'm interested in making it better.

Answer (score 3):

An idea is tu use pseudo-element to create your backgrounds and you can easily create the effect you want. The drawbacks is that you will have more CSS and you have to add your content inside a `span` in order to correctly set `z-index` values.

**Using 2 pseudo-elements:**

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background 1s;
  position: relative;
}

a span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

a:before,
a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: background 1s;
}

a:after {
  z-index: 2;
}

a:hover::before {
  background: red;
  transition: background 0s;
}

a:active::after {
  background: blue;
  transition: background 0s;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)"><span>Test link</span></a>
```

**Using only one pseudo element:**

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background 1s;
  position: relative;
}

a span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: background 1s;
}

a:hover {
  background: red;
  transition: background 0s;
}

a:active::before {
  background: blue;
  transition: background 0s;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)"><span>Test link</span></a>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's an interesting idea. The z-index isn't actually needed in the second version. And if the link only contains text and I know it in advance, I can put it into the `content` attribute and get around with no `<span>` at all. But it's not that practical yet. So if I wanted to use this in a generic way, I'd have to wrap all such link's content into an additional span element.

Comment: @ygoe yes these are the drawbacks :) i tried to find a way without additionnal HTML but it was a bit tricky ... by the way you can make this a generic way if you add a small jQuery code that will add the span for you using a specific class for this animation, if you are interested in such solution i can added it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did based on Temani Afif's answer. It doesn't need the additional `<span>` inside the link but instead an additional `data-text` attribute on it, and it only works for plain text content (no images etc.).

The example has two test links, one with and one without the attribute, to show the fallback behaviour that's basically what I have in the question.

Not sure which is "better". It probably depends on the circumstances. I just wanted to add this solution as well.

```css
a
{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background 1s;
  position: relative;
}

a:hover
{
  background: red;
  transition: background 0s;
}

a[data-text]::before
{
  content: attr(data-text);
  color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  background: transparent;
  transition: background 1s, color 1s;
}

a[data-text]:active::before,
a:not([data-text]):active
{
  color: white;
  background: blue;
  transition: background 0s;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-text="Test link">Test link</a>

<a href="javascript:void(0)">Test link</a>
```

Comment: the first one seems good but in the second one you don't have the ease transition from active to hover

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, that's intentional. The second is a plain link element with no markup extras. It doesn't support the nice special case that the first does. Just for comparison. The `:not` part in the CSS was added to handle that.